# Проблема с регулярными выражениям python

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

при отработке

```
extract_page = re.compile(r"(GET|PUT|POST|HEAD|OPTIONS|DELETE).(?P<date>\/[a-zA-Z]+\/[a-zA-Z0-9]+.[a-z]+)")
extract_data = extract_page.search(log_string)
return extract_data.group('date')
```

Выдает ошибку:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Почему?

Comment: Совпадение не найдено. У вас, наверное, проблемы с регулярным выражением.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно проверять результат [re.search](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search). Если регулярка не найдет строку по шаблону, то вернет `None`:

> Return None if no position in the string matches the pattern

Пример проверки:

```
extract_page = re.compile(r"(GET|PUT|POST|HEAD|OPTIONS|DELETE).(?P<date>\/[a-zA-Z]+\/[a-zA-Z0-9]+.[a-z]+)")
extract_data = extract_page.search(log_string)
if extract_data:
    return extract_data.group('date')
```